# "lambda" vs. "operator.attrgetter('xxx')" as a sort key function

Tags: python, lambda

I am looking at some code that has a lot of sort calls using comparison functions, and it seems like it should be using key functions.

If you were to change `seq.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x.xxx, y.xxx))`, which is preferable:

```
seq.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('xxx'))
```

or:

```
seq.sort(key=lambda a: a.xxx)
```

I would also be interested in comments on the merits of making changes to existing code that works.

Comment: This question has been undeleted as per the discussion on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378445/4909087). OP, would you be willing to accept a more current, up to date answer for python3.7+?

Comment: By all means - I'm intrigued at the comments that "one is clearly better than the other," without indication of which is which.

Comment: Empirically, non-lambda callbacks (especially operator functions that operate at C speed) have shown to be Superior to lambdas in terms of performance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When choosing purely between `attrgetter('attributename')` and `lambda o: o.attributename` as a sort key, then using `attrgetter()` is the *faster* option of the two.

Remember that the key function is only applied once to each element in the list, before sorting, so to compare the two we can use them directly in a time trial:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> from random import randint
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, field
>>> @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     bar: int = field(default_factory=lambda: randint(1, 10**6))
...
>>> testdata = [Foo() for _ in range(1000)]
>>> def test_function(objects, key):
...     [key(o) for o in objects]
...
>>> stmt = 't(testdata, key)'
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import test_function as t, testdata; '
>>> tests = {
...     'lambda': setup + 'key=lambda o: o.bar',
...     'attrgetter': setup + 'from operator import attrgetter; key=attrgetter("bar")'
... }
>>> for name, tsetup in tests.items():
...     count, total = Timer(stmt, tsetup).autorange()
...     print(f"{name:>10}: {total / count * 10 ** 6:7.3f} microseconds ({count} repetitions)")
...
    lambda: 130.495 microseconds (2000 repetitions)
attrgetter:  92.850 microseconds (5000 repetitions)
```

So applying `attrgetter('bar')` 1000 times is roughly 40 μs faster than a `lambda`. That's because calling a *Python* function has a certain amount of overhead, more than calling into a native function such as produced by `attrgetter()`.

This speed advantage translates into faster sorting too:

```
>>> def test_function(objects, key):
...     sorted(objects, key=key)
...
>>> for name, tsetup in tests.items():
...     count, total = Timer(stmt, tsetup).autorange()
...     print(f"{name:>10}: {total / count * 10 ** 6:7.3f} microseconds ({count} repetitions)")
...
    lambda: 218.715 microseconds (1000 repetitions)
attrgetter: 169.064 microseconds (2000 repetitions)
```

Comment: I would like to understand what the `native function such as produced by attrgetter()` is and why it's faster. I looked into [attrgetter source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/operator.py#L254). So for example when sorting, attrgetter's `__call__()` is invoked, which in turn invokes `self._call()`, a Python function. I don't know how lambda is constructed internally, but wouldn't the exact same thing happen (invoke `__call__()`, then the actual Python function)? What am I missing?

Comment: @onepiece: the `operator` module implementation is only there in case the C extensions can't be imported. The *real* source code is found in [`Modules/_operator.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_operator.c#L1138-L1480), and [imported into `operator.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/operator.py#L407-L412), replacing the Python versions. By native function I mean objects implemented in an extension module written in C, that comes with your Python installation.

Comment: I see. Here's my understanding of the direct comparison:

When `attrgetter` is called: 
1. call [attrgetter_call()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_operator.c#L1310) (C level) - how does Python know to use this when the `attrgetter` instance is called? 
1a. find and return attribute (C level). 

For lambda: 
1. call `__call__()` (Python level)
2. call the lambda's actual method (Python-level)
2a. find and return attribute (Python level).

Comment: I'm not sure if my lambda understanding is correct - where is the source code for lambda/functions? But assuming it is, lambda has an extra Python call due to `__call__()`, and the rest of steps start at Python level and proceed to C, while for attrgetter, the steps start at C level.

Comment: @onepiece: there is no `_call` in the C implementation. The Python implementation just used an indirect function call (`_call` is set to one of two options, in `__init__`) to simplify the logic of differentiating between the multiple attributes (returning a tuple) and single attribute (returning a single value) cases.

Comment: @onepiece: a `lambda` is just syntax, it creates a function the same way the `def ...(): ...` syntax does, albeit with limits on what can be used in the 'body' of the function. There is no extra call anywhere. Python gives you, the developer, the opportunity to hook into `...()` call syntax by implementing a `__call__` method but that doesn't mean that everything that is callable is called through `__call__`.

Comment: @onepiece this is otherwise really not the place to conduct an in-depth discussion of how Python functions work, sorry.

Answer (score 24):

"Making changes to existing code that works" is how programs evolve;-).  Write a good battery of tests that give known results with the existing code, save those results (that's normally known as "golden files" in a testing context); then make the changes, rerun the tests, and verify (ideally in an automated way) that the only changes to the tests' results are those that are specifically **intended** to be there -- no undesired or unexpected side effects.  One can use more sophisticated quality assurance strategies, of course, but this is the gist of many "integration testing" approaches.

As for the two ways to write simple `key=` function, the design intent was to make `operator.attrgetter` faster by being more specialized, but at least in current versions of Python there's no measurable difference in speed.  That being the case, for this special situation I would recommend the `lambda`, simply because it's more concise and general (and I'm not usually a lambda-lover, mind you!-).

Comment: i concur with alex's answer (that's he's no lambda lover) :-) but also second the notion of the lambda. in your example above, it may be a tiny bit faster because you don't have to look up either `operator` or `operator.attrgetter()`... you have the actual function object already! however, it is barely noticeable as alex has said already, but the `lambda` solution does win Python Zen points by being easier to read.

Comment: @wescpy both `attrgetter` and `lambda` have to do the same amount of work to look up the attribute, and both are created once, when you start the sort. But a lambda requires a new Python Stack frame (relatively expensive) for each call, where an `attrgetter` instance doesn’t, so `attrgetter` is faster. I find an inline lambda no easier to read than an `attrgetter`, so for me, `attrgetter` wins.

Answer (score 6):

As stated by previous commenters, `attrgetter` is slightly faster, but for a lot of situations the difference is marginal (~microseconds).

Regarding readability, I personally prefer `lambda` as it's a construct that people will have seen before in different contexts, so it will probably be easier for others to read and understand.

One other caveat is that your IDE should be able to signal a typo on the attr name when using `lambda`, unlike using `attrgetter`.

In general I tend to choose the construct that does not require an extra import if the alternative is easy enough to write and read.