# Python min function with a list of objects

Tags: python

How can use the `key` argument for the `min` function to compare a list of objects's 1 attribute?

Example

```
class SpecialNumber:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.number = i

li = [SpecialNumber(1), SpecialNumber(3), SpecialNumber(2)]
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter

```
from operator import attrgetter
min_num = min(li,key=attrgetter('number'))
```

Sample interactive session:

```
>>> li = [SpecialNumber(1), SpecialNumber(3), SpecialNumber(2)]
>>> [i.number for i in li]
[1, 3, 2]
>>> min_num = min(li,key=attrgetter('number'))
>>> print min_num.number
1
```

Comment: is the `operator.attrgetter` function faster than using a lambda function?

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica yes it is faster https://stackoverflow.com/q/2705104/2038264

Answer (score 62):

It's:

```
min(li, key=lambda x: x.number)
```

you need a function that accepts a `SpecialNumber` and returns its element.

Comment: Is it possible to not return the number element by return the `SpecialNumber` class?

Comment: It does return the `SpecialNumber` object by default. To get the lowest element, just run: `min(li, key=lambda x: x.number).number`

Answer (score 16):

I'd do it by overriding [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

```
class SpecialNumber:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.number = i

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<SpecialNumber(%d)>' % self.number

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.number, other.number)

li = [SpecialNumber(1), SpecialNumber(3), SpecialNumber(2)]
print min(li) # <SpecialNumber(1)>
```

Comment: Note that for Python 3.0 __cmp__ is gone.  So you can use __lt__, __eq__ and the functools.total_ordering decorator on the class to make it work (or define __lt__, __gt__, __le__, __ge__, __eq__, __ne__)

Comment: those should have been double underscores -- apparently it's markdown for bold...

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert Do we need to define all these methods (__lt, __gt, __le, __ge, __eq, __ne)?

Comment: No, you only need to defined __lt_ _ and __eq_ _  (without the space in the final underscores) and if you have added @functools.total_ordering to the class, it will generate all the other functions for you.

Answer (score 1):

the getattr version is faster

```
import random
from operator import attrgetter

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = random.random()

t = [Test() for i in range(10000)]

%timeit min(t, key=lambda x: x.a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 790 µs per loop

%timeit min(t,key=attrgetter('a'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 µs per loop
```