# What does this for loop inside a min function do?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding what this line of code does

`dist, xy = min((getDistance(position, xy), xy) for xy in coordinates)`

`position` and `xy` are both int tuples that look like (x, y) while `coordinates` is a list of int tuples

I thought that it would be equivalent to

```
for xy in coordinates:
   dist = min(getDistance(position, xy), xy)
```

But this doesn't make sense as getDistance returns an int, and you cannot compare an int with a tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python min function with a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085467/python-min-function-with-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's generator comprehension. It's like list comprehension but returns a generator which is evaluated lazily, when items are needed (as opposed to keeping whole thing in memory - like creating a list would do).

The most basic equivalent, without creating new tuples, would be:

```py
current_result_dist, current_result_xy = coordinates[0] # or some max value to init this
for xy in coordinates:
    if getDistance(position, xy) < current_result_dist:
        current_result_dist = getDistance(position, xy)
        current_result_xy = xy
```

Now, when it comes to tuples being compared, first element is compared first. Other elements will get compared only if first ones are equal. It's exactly like with strings - "abc" < "xyz" because "a"<"x" - we don't have to care about the other characters!

That's why the snippet uses `(getDistance(position, xy), xy)` tuple as single element, and not getDistance only - it will select min distance (first element of the tuple), and we will get our corresponding xy as additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only tuples internally, it ends up giving you the coordinate tuple that's closest. Each entry given to `min` is a `(dist, (x, y))` pair. `min` operates across these tuples (and not against a set of tuples *and* ints as in your example).

```
(1, (2, 3))
(2, (18, 32))
(18, (45, 42))
```

Comparison between tuples are performed from the left to the right, so it'll give the tuple with the lowest distance, returning `(dist, (x, y))`, in this case `(1, (2, 3))`.

The comparison happens between two tuples: `(1, (2, 3))` and `(2, (18, 32))` - not between `1` and `(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generator :

```py
((getDistance(position, xy), xy) for xy in coordinates)
```

Algorithmically, it is equivalent to using a list like this (the difference being that the generator is not stored entirely in memory):

```py
tuples = []
for xy in coordinates:
    tuples.append((getDistance(position, xy), xy))
```

So you get a tuple generator of which you get the minimum.

`min` returns the minimal tuple produced by the generator. (Note that when passing a generator to a function, you may strip the surrounding parenthesis.)

Tuple comparison in Python compares first item, then in case of equality second item, etc.

So in the end, you get

```py
    (distance(position, xy), xy)
```

where `distance(position, xy)` is minimal which means `xy` is the closest item to `position`.

---

TBH, I find the implementation a bit twisted. It works for sure, but it is a bit hard to read. I try to write code that is more explicit for future readers (including myself).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the minimum is of tuples, so you should expect a tuple as result, not just `dist`, and if you loop like that, expecting to incrementally get the current best result, you need to feed the previous "winning" tuple back into the `min` function.

It is somewhat equivalent to:

```
dist = float("inf")
closestxy = None
for xy in coordinates:
   dist, closestxy = min( (dist, closestxy), (getDistance(position, xy), xy) )
```

Or also:

```
lst = []
for xy in coordinates:
   lst.append( (getDistance(position, xy), xy) )
dist, xy = min(lst)
```

These are not *exactly* the same, as the original does not initialise any variable, nor does it create a list. But you get the idea.