# Python query - method as iterable?

Tags: python, oop, methods, iteration

I'm trying to emulate the following output (from Marakana.com's [excellent Python tutorial](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/oop.html#_emulation):

```
>>> for c in lot.cars_by_age():
...     print c
1981 VW Vanagon
1988 Buick Regal
2010 Audi R8
```

My code so far:

```
class ParkingLot(object):
    def __init__(self, spaces, cars=[]):
        self.spaces = spaces
        self.cars = cars
    def park(self, car):
        if self.spaces == 0:
            print "The lot is full."
        else:
            self.spaces -= 1
            self.cars.append(car)
    def __iter__(self):
        return (car for car in self.cars)

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (car.year, car.make, car.model)
```

I want to add a method (cars_by_age()) to the ParkingLot() class. However, this method somehow needs to be iterable, as per the sample code. I'm not sure how to do this - for a class, you define an **iter** function, but how do you do that for a method?

Comment: A word of warning: in general, in Python, you want to avoid having mutable objects (like lists) as the default parameter (as with `cars=[]` in your init method above). Full details as to why here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that the *method* is iterable; the value *returned* by the method is iterable. A  `cars_by_age` implementation could simply return a list of `Car`s.

```
def cars_by_age(self):
    return sorted(self.cars, key=lambda car: car.year)
```

Use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) to create a new sorted list, and use [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to specify that you want to sort by the car's `year` attribute.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import attrgetter

class ParkingLot(object):
    def __init__(self, spaces, cars=None):
        self.spaces = max(spaces, 0)
        self.cars = cars or []
    def park(self, car):
        if self.spaces > 0:
            self.spaces -= 1
            self.cars.append(car)
        else:
            print "The lot is full."
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.cars)
    def cars_by_age(self):
        return sorted(self.cars, key=attrgetter("year"), reverse=True)

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.year, self.make, self.model)
```

Comment: Just for the record (I had to look this up myself, BTW): [`lambda` vs `attrgetter`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705104/lambda-vs-operator-attrgetterxxx-as-sort-key-function-in-python)

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thank you for the reference; I see no real difference in speed or readability between the two, so let's call it a matter of taste.