# Return the smallest element value in a list of lists

Tags: python

Given a list of lists like this :

```
[["fileA",7],["fileB",4],["fileC",17],["fileD",15]]
```

How would you return the first element associated to the smallest value ? In this instance "fileB" since it has the smallest value (4). I'm guessing the shortest way would be using list comprehension .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, a list comprehension wouldn't be the best tool for this.  Instead, you should use [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min), its [key function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#key-function), and [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [["fileA",7],["fileB",4],["fileC",17],["fileD",15]]
>>> min(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
['fileB', 4]
>>> min(lst, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'fileB'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without importing anything you can do:

```
min(lst, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Comment: I would say @sashkello's answer is better according to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705104/lambda-vs-operator-attrgetterxxx-as-sort-key-function-in-python

Comment: @Mehdi That's a 2010 answer, I'm not sure if something has changed since, but it could have.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this weird idea which doesn't use anything but simple generator expression:

```
min((x[1], x[0]) for x in lst)[1]
```

It is based on the fact that the minimization is done on the first element of a tuple/list by default.

Comment: That isn't actually a list comprehension.  It is a generator expression.

Comment: @iCodez True, edited. (I reckon this is what OP meant when he talked about list comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just convert the data to a dictionary, since that immediately seems a lot more sensible than having a list of lists. Then you can manipulate and access your data more easily.

```
myLists = [["fileA",7],["fileB",4],["fileC",17],["fileD",15]]
myDict = dict(myLists)
min(myDict, key=myDict.get)
# 'fileB'
```

Comment: or `myDict = dict(myLists)` :)

Comment: While this is not the best answer to the current question, it probably would be the way to go if the list is used for other things down the line.

Comment: @gnibbler Cool, didn't know it would automatically convert appropriately. Although it does basically the same thing in the dict comprehension.