# Finding minimum value from a dictionary whose values are lists of objects

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of Python Objects of type class Service. There is another dictionary `grps` where the objects are grouped according to a data member. Objects in the same group have exactly the same value for the data member according to which it is grouped.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class service:
    def __init__(self, tasknum, candidatenum, features, cost):
        self.tasknum = tasknum
        self.candidatenum = candidatenum
        self.features = features
        self.cost = cost

s11 = service(1,1, features = [1], cost = 30)
s12 = service(1,2, features = [1], cost = 50)
s13 = service(1,3, features = [1], cost = 70)
s14 = service(1,4, features = [1], cost = 200)
s15 = service(1,5, features = [2], cost = 20)

lst = []
lst.append(s11)
lst.append(s12)
lst.append(s13)
lst.append(s14)
lst.append(s15)

grps = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    grps[tuple(x.features)].append(x)
```

In the above, there are two groups, one corresponding to `features = [1]`, and one corresponding to `features = [2]`.

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(1,): [<__main__.service object at 0x7efe19a2d6d8>, <__main__.service object at 0x7efe19a2d4e0>, <__main__.service object at 0x7efe1d7e9550>, <__main__.service object at 0x7efe1d7e9588>], (2,): [<__main__.service object at 0x7efe1d7e95c0>]})
```

For each such group, I would like to return a service object having the minimum cost value, that is, in the above,  the first group would return `s11` service and the second group would return `s15` service since that is the only object in the group.

And is there any better way to do this without using the dictionary, like can this be done by just using lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a list comprehension you can call `min()` on each member of the groups and use a key that gets the `cost` attribute. [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) handy for this:

```
from operator import attrgetter
# array of min-cost services
mins = [min(g, key = attrgetter('cost')) for g in grps.values()]

# just the costs
[c.cost for c in mins] # [30, 20]
```

Comment: Is there a tradeoff between `lambda x: x.cost` versus `attrgetter('cost')` as a key @MarkMeyer ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that's good question. Ii think `attrgetter` is nicer to read. There's some discussion [here suggesting it's faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705104/lambda-vs-operator-attrgetterxxx-as-sort-key-function-in-python), although probably not noticeable for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `min()` on each sublist on the `cost` attribute, and append those objects to a list. `min_costs` will be the objects with mimimum costs.

```
#List to hold all objects with min costs
min_costs = []

for k, v in grps.items():
    # Calculate minimum for all sublists on cost attribute
    min_costs.append(min(v, key=lambda x:x.cost))

#Print the costs of objects with min costs
print([c.cost for c in min_costs])
#[30, 20]
```

A one liner list-comprehension for the same will be

```
min_costs = [min(v, key=lambda x:x.cost) for v in grps.values()]
```

Comment: I would like to return the objects not just the costs

Comment: Updated @kauray Please check!

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have a dictionary, find the object having minimum cost with `min` and its `key` argument:

```
for k, v in grps.items():
    print(min(v, key=lambda x: x.cost))

# <__main__.service object at 0xeac0f090>
# <__main__.service object at 0xeac0f110>
```